# Given a semicircle ,Find a ratio

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> On a semicircle with diameter $AB$ and centre $S$, points $C$ and $D$ are given such that point $C$ belongs to arc $AD$. Suppose angle $CSD$=120°.Let $E$ be the point of intersection of the straight lines $AC$ & $BD$ and $F$ the point b of intersection of the straight lines $AD$ & $BC$.Find $\frac{EF}{AB}$.

As $AB$ is the diameter . Therefore, Angle $ACB$ and $ADB$ are right angle. So, $F$ is the orthocentre of triangle $ABE$.But I cant do after I somebody help me.

Comment: have you made a Picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\angle DAC ={1\over 2}\angle DSC = 60^{\circ}$ so is $\angle CED = 30^{\circ}$. Thus $\triangle ADE$ is a half of equilateral triangle and so $AE = 2AD$ and $ED=\sqrt{3}AD$. Now since $\triangle ADB\sim \triangle EDF$ we have $${EF\over AB}={ED\over AD} ={\sqrt{3}\over 1}$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Assuming $AB=2$ we clearly have $CD=\sqrt{3}$. $F$ is the orthocenter of $ABE$ and $\widehat{AEB}=30^\circ$.
 Let us consider the circumcircles of $AEB$ and $AFB$:

[image]

It is pretty clear by angle chasing that the length of $EF$ is constant and it equals $AH$, where $H$ belongs to the circumcircle of $AEB$ and $\widehat{HAB}=90^\circ$. It follows that $EF=HA=\color{blue}{\sqrt{3}\, AB}$.